# Sql datetime formatting causing slowness

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, reporting-services

I am experiencing vastly different performance from a stored procedure and it appears to be from the way a date is formatted. I was optimzing my stored procedure in SSMS and used the date format N'05/21/2017'. This is an SSRS report and when I looked at what was being sent into the stored procedure I saw the format was '2017-07-07 00:00:00'. Is there a way I can transform the date SSRS gives me to get the same performance as the first date format?  Or can I change the query to better use the other date format. Here are the two runs of the report.

```
EXEC    [dbo].[my_report]
        @StartDate = N'05/11/2017',
        @EndDate = N'05/21/2017'
GO

EXEC    [dbo].[my_report]
        @StartDate = '2017-05-11 00:00:00',
        @EndDate ='2017-05-21 00:00:00'
GO
```

The query is using it to get dates between the range.

```
AND ecl.My_DateTime between @StartDate and DATEADD(day,1,@EndDate)
```

The stored procedure executes in under a second for the first example and the second execution takes over a minute to run.

Comment: one minute? I think may the problem is something else. You could use the SMALLDATETIME instead of the DATETIME  data type if the hour is does not need to be stored.

Comment: Im just realzing that this might be a data issue in the date range i am looking at and not a conversion issue.

Comment: First, you should use dates, not datetimes (since you're adding a day to the end date).  In your current situation, a record would be included if it was imported at midnight the day after the end date - which is not what you want.  Better to make `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` types of `DATE` - and change your condition to `CAST(ecl.My_DateTime as date) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate`.

Comment: What is the argument to the stored procedure?  Why do I suspect that it is a string and not a date?

Comment: @GordonLinoff It was a datetime but i changed it to date.

Comment: What data type is ecl.My_DateTime?  What data type are the StartDate and EndDate parameters assigned in the stored procedure?

Comment: @Jesse They were are all datetimes.

Comment: Hmm.. well that is strange.  One thing that comes to mind is declaring two additional datetime variables in the procedure, assign the parameters to those variables and use them.  Perhaps parameter sniffing is messing with this procedure.

Comment: " It was a datetime but i changed it to date" did it make any difference?  You may be getting a performance boost if the query compiler is eliminating an implicit cast but only when sniffing detects that one really isn't needed.  Or the other way around.  Suffering an implicit cast when it detects one is required.